# Please help: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > No signature of method

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I've editted Flutter source code like author's documentation but always having this error when building APK file:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'F:\MyProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 34

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_7lhgwn6g10f1dc3sk72t2tmig.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_7lhgwn6g10f1dc3sk72t2tmig$_run_closure2) values: [build_7lhgwn6g10f1dc3sk72t2tmig$_run_closure2@9578636]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... 2.787ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Line 34 in \android\app\build.gradle' is started with **android**.

This is app\build.gradle file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {

compileSdkVersion 33

lintOptions {
disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
// TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
applicationId "my-package-name"
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 33
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
multiDexEnabled true
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

signingConfigs {
release {
keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
}
}

buildTypes {
release {

signingConfig signingConfigs.release

minifyEnabled true
useProguard true

proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}

flutter {
source '../..'
}

dependencies {
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
implementation('androidx.work:work-runtime') {
version {
strictly '2.6.0'
}
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Flutter doctor** => No issues found!

**Flutter --version**

Flutter 3.1.0-9.0.pre • channel dev • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f28e570c8c (3 weeks ago) • 2022-06-14 13:39:33 -0500
Engine • revision 74ee6b5afd
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-165.1.beta) • DevTools 2.14.0

**gradle --version**

---

### Gradle 7.4.2

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          18.0.1.1 (Oracle Corporation 18.0.1.1+2-6)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you added key.properties and the jks file?

Comment: Yes sir. I totally generated jks file and put it’s correct info to key.properties file. Do you think gradle in my pc has problem?

Comment: Are you able to build a freah flutter project? If yes check the difference in gradle files please. I think the gradle file has some issues

Comment: I'm using this PC and build another Fullter project successfully. Can you tell me how to check and fix gradle's issues? I'm rather new to Flutter and Android Studio. Thank you.

Comment: Im facing this issue now. Are you able to share a solution please?

Answer (score 3):

On mine it was caused by proguard issues. Comment out

```
useProguard true

proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a backup of your project and use this Gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "package id here"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies{
    
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

Add your package id. Then do a flutter clean. Delete pub spec.lock file.. Run flutter pub get and try again.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue
i update gradle
from
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
to
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'

it fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue after updating flutter to 3.3.9

but the main problem was the update of the kotlin version (i upgraded it to 1.7.21) and the update kotlin gradle plugin (new 7.1.2)

there were a small warning regarding useProguard is deprecated. after removing `useProguard false` from build.gradle everything works as expected